# RewriteRule passing url parts through as arguments not coming through to php script

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL

```
 http://localhost/xxxx/cat/History?randomArg=2
```

that I want to run

<strike>http://localhost/xxxx/cat/edit.php?name=History&randomArg=2</strike>

```
 http://localhost/xxxx/cat.php?name=History&randomArg=2
```

> (POST EDIT#2 Correction I did originally ask for *edit.php* but I meant *cat.php*)

and I have a RewriteRule that works on my live server

```
RewriteRule "^(.*)xxxx.*/cat/(.*)?(.*)$" $1/xxxx/cat.php?name=$2&t=123$3[QSA]
```

and when I run a test via the htaccess tester https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=f9987308-2570-4fbe-a769-4e5031a96578, I get...

```
RewriteRule "^(.*)xxxx.*/cat/(.*)?(.*)$" $1/xxxx/cat.php?name=$2&t=123$3[QSA]
```

...
[image]

Firstly, I can't see why $3 (e.g. "randomArg=2") isn't coming through on the https://htaccess.madewithlove.com tester site.

Secondly, I have plugged this into my WAMP environment and although I see cat.php running I don't see the RewriteRule working**

my cat.php code reads:

```
echo "<LI>_GET[*]:<PRE>" . print_r($_GET, true) . "</PRE>";
echo "<LI>_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]:<PRE>" . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . "</PRE>";
echo "<LI>_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]:<PRE>" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "</PRE>";

if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    echo "<LI>GET[name]=<PRE>" . $_GET['name'] . "</PRE>";
    $params = explode("/", $_GET['name']);
    $site = array_shift($params);
    echo "<LI>shifted:[$site]";
}
else echo "<LI>No GET[name]";

if (isset($_GET['t'])) echo "<LI>t:<PRE>" . $_GET['t'] . "</PRE>";
else echo "<LI>No GET[t]";
```

and the output for `http://localhost/xxxx/cat/History?randomArg=2` reads:

```
_GET[*]:Array
(
    [randomArg] => 2
)
_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]:/xxxx/cat.php
_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]:/xxxx/cat/History?randomArg=2
No GET[name]
No GET[t]
```

** But if the rule isn't working then why is cat.php running (as the URL asks for "cat/History"?

(Windows, Apache 2.4.41, PHP5.4)

    As a sidenote/test, putting this into my LAMP (Apache 2.4.6) environment using a similar rule (but using sss.xxx.com/testHtaccess/History) with the following rule...
    ```
    RewriteRule "^(.*)testHtaccess/(.*)?(.*)$" $1/testHtaccess.php?name=$2&t=123$3[QSA]
    ```
    ...  does partially work (it passes "name" through, but still no $3)!

So how can I get my localhost rule to work?

** **ADDITIONAL (POST EDIT#1):**

For what it's worth, and as it's pointed out by anubhava (below) I notice I have the following `httpd-vhosts.conf` default settings:

```
 # Virtual Hosts
 #
 <VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost
   ServerAlias localhost
   DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
   <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
     Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
     AllowOverride All
     Require local
   </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

> +MultiViews will explain "cat" turning into "cat.php"

Comment: You want to rewrite to `/xxxx/cat/edit.php` or `/xxxx/cat.php` ?

Comment: Thanks and well spotted anubhava, I did say edit.php but meant cat.php (/xxxx/cat.php); I have added a POST EDIT#2 to hopefully clear that up.

Answer (score 3):

- You cannot match query string using `RewriteRule` (though you don't need to match here).
- You appear to have `MultiViews` (content negotiation service) turned on.

You can use this code in your site root .htaccess:

```bash
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond ^(.*/cat)/([\w-]+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1.php?name=%2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Using `QSA` your original query string will automatically be appended to new target.

Comment: Thanks for the MultiViews note - that adds up; but the RewriteRule seems to make no difference

Comment: Do you want to rewrite to `edit.php` or `cat.php` and are these files at same directory level as htaccess ?

Comment: Thanks and well spotted anubhava, I did say edit.php but meant cat.php (/xxxx/cat.php); I have added a POST EDIT#2 to hopefully clear that up. 

htaccess: good guess - It seems that htaccess was in a sub-folder [as cat.php] but now I have moved it to the same in the same folder I get a "404 Not Found" when requesting `http://localhost/xxxx/cat/History` with `RewriteRule ^(xxxx/cat)/([\w-]+)/?$ xxxx/cat.php?name=$2&t=123 [L,QSA,NC]`

Comment: ok does `http://localhost/xxxx/cat.php` work fine?  Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit any page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: changing `RewriteRule` to `xRewriteRule` causes the page to return `Internal Server Error.....The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.....`; (with the `xRewriteRule` switched back... running `http://localhost/xxxx/cat.php?name=History` works; running `http://localhost/xxxx/cat/History` with the rule `RewriteRule "^(xxxx/cat)/([\w-]+)/?$" xxxx/cat.php?name=$2[L,QSA,NC]` returns `Not Found.. the requested URL was not found on this server`

Comment: Looked at your answer. I was always suspicious of `xxx/` in URL and that's why I asked first question about directory structure. If .htaccess is at same level as `cat.php` then we cannot use `xxx/` in `RewriteRule` and it will simply become `RewriteRule ^(cat)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?name=$2 [L,QSA,NC]`. I will post another version of rule that is agnostic to .htaccess location. Another point is never to reply on any online testing sire to test .htaccess rules. Always test it using your local Apache.

Answer (score 1):

Ok - lots of random variation attempts seems [and based on [anubhava's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/548225/anubhava) very gratefully received persistence] to have found the following works:

```
RewriteRule "^(cat)/([\w- ]+)/?.*$" xxxx/cat.php?name=$2&t=12345 [L,QSA,NC]
```

> although https://htaccess.madewithlove.com/ tells me that the rule was
> not met! :-(

(I wish there was a more scientific way to develop RewriteRules)

So using the rule (above), and running `http://localhost/xxxx/cat/Histor5ys?o=91` with the following php:

```
echo "<LI>_GET[*]:<PRE>" . print_r($_GET, true) . "</PRE>";
echo "<LI>_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]:<PRE>" . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . "</PRE>";
echo "<LI>_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]:<PRE>" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "</PRE>";


if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
    echo "<LI>GET[name]=<PRE>" . $_GET['name'] . "</PRE>";
}
else echo "<LI>No GET[name]";


if (isset($_GET['t'])) echo "<LI>t:<PRE>" . $_GET['t'] . "</PRE>";
else echo "<LI>No GET[t]";


if (isset($_GET['o'])) echo "<LI>o:<PRE>" . $_GET['o'] . "</PRE>";
else echo "<LI>No GET[o]";
```

outputs ...

```
_GET[*]:Array
(
    [name] => Histor5ys
    [t] => 123456
    [o] => 91
)
_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]:/xxxx/cat.php
_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]:/xxxx/cat/Histor5ys?o=91
GET[name]=Histor5ys
shifted:[Histor5ys]
t:123456
o:91
```